# CSOM File object ID property

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, asp.net

What is the correct way to initialize or call File obj ID property? I don't see it as a default object property. I also tried calling via:

- File.ListItemAllFields["ID"]

That failed. I did notice the following property:

- File.ListId

I assumed that was not the File ID, but list ID containing File?

Comment: show some code. You probably didn't `Load()` it. And let us know what you got when you ran it.

Comment: @DerekGusoff File.UniqueId was the property I was looking for. I loaded the object just didn't see UniqueId as the ID property initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File.UniqueId was the property I was looking for.